# How to debug React Native project created with Expo using TypeScript

Tags: typescript, debugging, react-native, expo

I created an Expo boilerplate project that is using TypeScript.

When I run the app with `expo start`, the Chrome debugger opens up at `http://localhost:19001/debugger-ui/`, but in the devtools I can only see `.js` files:

[image]

How can I get my `.tsx` sourcefiles to show up?

I have `"sourceMap": true,` in `.tsconfig.json` and the `.map` files are generated along the `.js` files. Any more configuration I am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

It works out of the box with React Native Debugger. Imho it's better tool than Chrome devtools, because it has also view Inspector and Redux debugger.

1. `expo init ts-expo-demo`, template: » tabs (TypeScript)
2. `expo start -a`
3. start React Native Debugger
4. once the app starts in the Android emulator, press Ctrl+M to open Expo menu
5. activate "Debug Remote JS" (this will open browser)
6. make note of the port in the opened browser (e.g. 19000)
7. close the browser
8. in React Native Debugger create new window and attach to the noted port, e.g. 19000 (press Ctrl+T to open new window)
9. reload the app in the emulator (press R twice, or Ctrl+M -> Reload)

This should connect to React Native Debugger and in Sources -> Page -> RNDebuggerWorker.js -> 127.0.0.1:19000 you will find uncompiled TypeScript files

```
React Native Debugger: 0.11.5
expo: 4.0.16
```

https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger/releases

[image]

Comment: does this work with Expo Go?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this [React Developer Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi) chrome extension.

With it you'll be able to debug the jsx files and even inspect into your react components hierarchy